# How to SELECT in SQL based on a value from the same table column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
| id | date       | team |
|----|------------|------|
| 1  | 2019-01-05 | A    |
| 2  | 2019-01-05 | A    |
| 3  | 2019-01-01 | A    |
| 4  | 2019-01-04 | B    |
| 5  | 2019-01-01 | B    |
```

How can I query the table to receive the most recent values for the teams?

For example, the result for the above table would be ids `1,2,4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by team order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In some databases a correlated subquery is faster with the right indexes (I haven't tested this with Postgres):

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.team = t.team);
```

And if you wanted only one row per team, then the canonical answer is:

```
select distinct on (t.team) t.*
from t
order by t.team, t.date desc;
```

However, that doesn't work in this case because you want all rows from the most recent date.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is large, consider the `max` analytic function in a subquery:

```
with cte as (
  select
    id, date, team,
    max (date) over (partition by team) as max_date
  from t
)
select id
from cte
where date = max_date
```

Notionally, `max` is O(n), so it should be pretty efficient.  I don't pretend to know the actual implementation on PostgreSQL, but my guess is it's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility, generic:

```
select * from t join (select max(date) date,team from t
                        group by team) tt
  using(date,team)
```

Answer (score 0):

Window function is the best solution for you.

```
select id
from (
  select team, id, rank() over (partition by team order by date desc) as row_num
  from table
) t
where row_num = 1
```

That query will return this table:

```
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 4  |
```

If you to get it one row per team, you need to use [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function.

```
select team, array_agg(id) ids
from (
  select team, id, rank() over (partition by team order by date desc) as row_num
  from table
) t
where row_num = 1
group by team
```

That query will return this table:

```
| team |  ids   |
|------|--------|
|  A   | [1, 2] |
|  B   | [4]    |
```